# Loading video-LLaVA with Huggingface transformers

Tags: huggingface, multimodal

On trying to load video-LLaVA with Huggingface on colab I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_errors.py in hf_raise_for_status(response, endpoint_name)
    285     try:
--> 286         response.raise_for_status()
    287     except HTTPError as e:

15 frames
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://huggingface.co/LanguageBind/Video-LLaVA-7B/resolve/main/preprocessor_config.json

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

EntryNotFoundError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
EntryNotFoundError: 404 Client Error. (Request ID: Root=1-65d6e313-109341163745f316481be0ac;97f03b13-3bac-447e-b9df-a109f451bc7c)

Entry Not Found for url: https://huggingface.co/LanguageBind/Video-LLaVA-7B/resolve/main/preprocessor_config.json.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py in cached_file(path_or_repo_id, filename, cache_dir, force_download, resume_download, proxies, token, revision, local_files_only, subfolder, repo_type, user_agent, _raise_exceptions_for_missing_entries, _raise_exceptions_for_connection_errors, _commit_hash, **deprecated_kwargs)
    434         if revision is None:
    435             revision = "main"
--> 436         raise EnvironmentError(
    437             f"{path_or_repo_id} does not appear to have a file named {full_filename}. Checkout "
    438             f"'https://huggingface.co/{path_or_repo_id}/{revision}' for available files."

OSError: LanguageBind/Video-LLaVA-7B does not appear to have a file named preprocessor_config.json. Checkout 'https://huggingface.co/LanguageBind/Video-LLaVA-7B/main' for available files.
the preprocessor_config.json is not present in the files ...how can I load the model?
```

This is the code I ran:

```
from transformers import AutoProcessor, AutoModelForCausalLM

processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained("LanguageBind/Video-LLaVA-7B")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("LanguageBind/Video-LLaVA-7B")
```